# Is there a way of 'detaching' a column from the rest for the purposes resizing the cells in it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Here's an example Excel spreadsheet.

[image]

Basically what it is an chart for time organisation, and I use the left most column for storing some notes (back log items etc).

Now I need to to keep the height of the timeslot cells regular to maintain scale.  To do this, I'm using the Format->Row Height tool.

With the lists in Column A however - these are constantly changing depending what's in them, and I often need to resize them.

It doesn't work to keep 'one list item in one cell' because a list item can be a lot of text that I want to see all of.

What I'd like to be able to do is resize/remerge these cells at will, without affecting the rest of the graph.

eg. (Note the row numbers).
[image]

To do this I had to unmerge, move the contents of the cells and remerge. Quite a pain.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, how about using a text box to save the list.

Comment: You could try centering the values across a number of cells, rather than merging

Comment: @user70926 - A text box is a perfectly acceptable solution here. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.